# Error trying to import cv2(opencv-python) package

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I am trying to access my webcam with cv2(opencv-python) package.

When I try to import it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Note: I am trying to import this package on putty, on Linode server - that might be useful information.

If anyone can explain to me what is happening and maybe solve the problem I will highly appreciate it!

Comment: Please install cv2 with "pip install opencv-python" Command

Comment: I did that already, no errors and after installing the error appears

Comment: Visit link may be it will helpful https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: I tried running the command pip3 check opencv-python and this is the output: 
pygobject 3.36.0 requires pycairo, which is not installed.
launchpadlib 1.10.13 requires testresources, which is not installed.

Comment: The problem is solved, thank you  @MuhammadRizwanMunawar !

Comment: Please specify the version when installing with pip Ex. "pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30"

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Install `opencv-python-headless` instead of `opencv-python`. Server (headless) environments do not have GUI packages installed which is why you are seeing the error. `opencv-python` depends on Qt which in turn depends on X11 related libraries.

Other alternative is to run `sudo apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev` which will provide the missing `libGL.so.1` if you want to use `opencv-python`. The `libgl1-mesa-dev` package might be named differently depending on your GNU/Linux distribution.

Full installation guide for `opencv-python` can be found from the package documentation: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python#installation-and-usage

Comment: libgl1-mesa-dev works fine with ubuntu 20.04 and corrects the problem

Comment: headless option solved my issue with docker, But not sure what it means exactly

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

`conda install -c fastai opencv-python-headless`