# Issues with python-opencv-headless

Tags: python, azure, pip, conda, opencv

I used to install opencv on my server using the conda yml file, as shown below

```
name: project_environment
dependencies:
- python=3.6.2
- pip=20.2.4

- pip:
  - pillow
  - numpy
  - opencv-python-headless==4.5.3.56
  - torch
  - torchvision
  - face-alignment==1.3.4
  - tensorflow==2.5.0
  - cmake
  - dlib
  
channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
```

Earlier, it used to work normally, but yesterday when i ran the script, i got the error

```
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This error was supposed to come if I install python-opencv, not in the headless version.
How can i debug, which package is causing the issue.

Comment: can you edit the question and add the output of `conda list -n project_environment --show-channel-urls`? That said, it looks like you may have so satisfy the libGL dependency with your system package manager. Why this error came up for you just now, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [skvark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5795428/skvark). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> Other alternative is to run `sudo apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev` which will provide the missing `libGL.so.1` if you want to use `opencv-python`. The `libgl1-mesa-dev` package might be named differently depending on your GNU/Linux distribution.

You can refer to [Error trying to import cv2(opencv-python) package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63978454/15969115), [ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710022/import-matplotlib-pyplot-as-plt-importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-obj) and [ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313610/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo)

You can also refer to closed issue on GitHub: [libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/370)